# Триггер и связь с отдельной таблицей

Tags: sql, mysql

Здравствуйте, с наступающим!

Есть такой триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `InsertAnswer` AFTER INSERT ON `answertoquestion`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO log Set 
   LogTime = NEW.AnswerToQuestionTime, 
   LogIdNote = NEW.idAnswerToQuestion, 
   LogName = NEW.AnswerToQuestionAnswer,
   LogType = 5;
END
```

В таблице **answertoquestion** есть поле **AnswerToQuestionIdQuestion**, указывающее на первичный ключ из таблицы question.

В триггере нужно определить эту связь и сделать так: ***LogName = question.questionName***

Подскажите как это можно сделать в самом тригере...

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как такой вариант прошел:
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `InsertAnswer`;

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `InsertAnswer` AFTER INSERT ON `answertoquestion`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO log Set 
   LogTime = NEW.AnswerToQuestionTime, 
   LogIdNote = NEW.idAnswerToQuestion, 
   LogName = (SELECT QuestionName FROM question WHERE idQuestion = NEW.AnswerToQuestionAnswer),
   LogType = 5,
   LogIdUser = NEW.AnswerToQuestionIdUser;

END
```